# Looking for advice on lighting my set

Tags: lighting

I have a bit of a crappy set for my Youtube stuff and, recently, I had a small windfall of sorts and was able to buy some lightbulbs and clamp lights. No, I couldn't buy a proper lighting kit, (it was only $50). I was hoping to get some recommendations on lighting my set.

So, here's what I have:

- 5 5000k 800 Lumen CFLs bulbs
- 5 6000k 1050 Lumen LED bulbs (accidentally ordered the wrong temp :(  )
- a 3 light rail above my set for lighting the background.
- a ceiling mount bar for clamping clamp lights to far away from the
  set. It currently has 3 clamp lights on it.
- 4 unused clap lights.

Below is a rough sketch of my current setup. [Here is a picture of it as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tK5V.jpg) The rectangles on the walls are both two shelves above another at 5' and 6'5".

My lighting setup feels uneven I'm trying to light as flatly as I can and I don't know where I should place those additional clamp lights. I'd really just like to make the most of my lights so I can reduce the ISO to get less noise. Also, I don't know how I should place these different temps so that I get a consistent coloring across the set (so that my white balance calibration will be consistent, that is).

I currently shoot at 30fps, 3.5 FStop, at 640 ISO on my Samsung NX300. [For reference: here is a video shot on my current lighting configuration.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-mHVF0kIYA)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qFPwNBU.jpg]

Comment: Have a look at 3 point lighting setups. There's heaps of tutorials around, this one's not bad: http://bhpho.to/1zNfha9